# How to change ``artifactory.access.client.max.connections`` in artifactory PRO and how will it effect the performance?

Tags: artifactory

I am trying to tune artifactory to get a good performance which has few takeway for our pro setup with derby.
one of which is to increase `artifactory.access.client.max.connections` from 50 
How to change `artifactory.access.client.max.connections` in artifactory PRO and how will it effect the performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, there is no need to modify the number of connections to Access as there are good caches on the Artifactory end and Artifactory should use much less than 50 connections.

If you want to increase that number, don't forget to increase the number of connections for Access port (default 8040) in tomcat's `server.xml` file as well.

Full disclosure - I'm a software architect in JFrog.